# Is there a way to force video output through an external monitor with a hotkey?

Tags: windows, display, shortcuts, hotkeys

I was wondering if there was a keyboard shortcut to force my laptop to display through the externally connected HDMI display.

Reason: my Aorus X7 Pro v3 cf2 currently has no screen, however the system itself functions perfectly. I could use the system fine prior to updating the graphics driver. Prior to updating, the output switched over automatically when plugged in. After the GPU driver update, it no longer auto switches to the connected screen.

Which brings me to my current problem. I know I can login to my Windows account without the screen as I can pop my password in when I know it is ready, and I can do stuff that triggers a sound such as sticky keys, etc.